# Set connection timeout on Electron's net.request

Tags: electron, httprequest

I'm trying to make a connection from an Electron app's renderer process using the suggested `net.request` library, as follows:

```js
const resData: string = await new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
  const req = net.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
  });
  req.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  req.write(xml);
  req.on("response", (response) => {
    resCode = response.statusCode;
    response.on("error", (e) => {
      reject(e);
    });
    response.on("data", (data) => {
      resolve(data.toString());
    });
  });
  req.on("error", (e) => {
    reject(e);
  })
  req.end();
}));
```

Everything works nicely, but when the host isn't reachable, it takes almost a minute to fail. Apparently the library doesn't offer any way to set a timeout, do I have to resort to `Promise.race()` with a timer and ignore the error or there's a cleaner way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

bit late , but i did this to do the time out ,

```
 request.on("response",(response=>{
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      if(response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 210 ){
        try{
        resolve({statusCode :  response.statusCode , data : JSON.parse(chunk)})
      }catch(e){
        resolve({statusCode :  response.statusCode , data : chunk.toString()})
      }
      }else{
        reject(`Failed to Do Request , Status Code : ${response.statusCode}` )
      }
    })

  setTimeout((()=>{!response && RequestOptions?.timeout ?rejects("Task Timed out"):response}), RequestOptions?.timeout);
  }))
```